# How to restrict access to a page in rails unless the user arrived by following the link from a specific page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am making an online computer based test in Rails. Each question has a page URL of the form `/questions/<id>` .
There is a 'next' button on each question's page which points to the next question, like `/questions/<another-id>`. I don't want the user to manually be able to type the URL of any question and go to that page.
Is there any way I can accomplish this, preferably a server-side solution.

Comment: As a simple (but not extremely secure) solution, may you have "next" button to submit a form (maybe empty), and only allow /questions/id path to be available in POST and not GET? This way typing in URL won't work as it will cause GET request.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

[Friendly ID Gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), That will convert your ID to a slug, So that the end-user can't determine what exactly is passing into URL parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I have one server side solution for you may be that will solve your problem explained here as below...

1. Assume, You have a fixed link where a user can start the test.
2. Once a user start the test, then add a question-id into session as like below...

   session[:current-question-id] = params[:question_id]
3. Always check the next question id by increasing one into sesssion question id, If matchs then show the question or do nothing redirect to back.

That solution will work, If you have sequence of question like 1,2,3...n.

Answer (score 1):

A bit like Bharat Soni:

You can build an url with an id built by combining your question Id and a random number linked to user session.

You can combine this two value using a SHA1 (or algorithm of your choice). For example :

question id :  123

secret session hash : 857c9e05-8ad0-4d6b-8112-5f442a731dc1 (`SecureRandom.uuid` on sessions#create)

Calculate your digest :

`Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "#{question_id}#{secret_session_hash}"`

=> e951774237433335a6c9c0928d5691ca0c2a31b5

build your url :

`website/question/123?key=e951774237433335a6c9c0928d5691ca0c2a31b5`

You have to ensure in your controller that the digest you receive in params[:key] is the same that the digest you calculate.

This way you can reasonably ensure that your user is not cheating and that he can't give url to another person.